# Creating a StreamWriter object throws an error: "The type String could not be converted to type Stream"

Tags: c#

I need to use a `StreamWriter` to write to a text file, but when I try to create one it throws this error:

> Argument 1: cannot convert from 'string' to 'System.IO.Stream'

On MSDN, the `StreamWriter` class has constructors that take one `Stream` or one `string`. I don't know why I can't use the right constructor, but I need to know if I'm doing something wrong.

Here's the code in question:

```
using(StreamWriter outputFile = new StreamWriter("Output/" + name + "-Verbose" + ".txt")) 
{ 
    // do stuff 
}
```

Comment: can u check the path is valid or not? Especially with characters like `/`... Best is check ur app by giving a proper path(like `D:\sample.txt`) first and then change to your desired path..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suspect you're writing a portable class library or something like that - if you look at the list of supported platforms in [`StreamWriter(String)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fysy0a4b(v=vs.110).aspx) it's considerably smaller than the list of supported platforms in [`StreamWriter(Stream)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wtbhzte9(v=vs.110).aspx). I suggest you just open a stream in whatever way is suitable for your target, and then wrap that in a `StreamWriter`.

Comment: Thanks for the solution! A lot of other people have also recommended that I just pass a stream, and I think that's the best way to do it.